# C free int array in function after writing value to other variable

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

i want to free memory allocated to int array in function after assign value from array element to integer variable.

I have code:

```
 int u(int n)
   {
    int* values = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n + 1);
    int out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
      values[i] = 1;
    if (n < 3) 
      return 1;
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
            values[i] = values[i - values[i - 1]] + values[i - values[i - 2]];
    }
    out = values[n];
    free(values);
    return out;
}
```

Why cant i free memory allocated to array after write a value to another variable? 
int out have another adress then allocated memory, all what i want to do its just give a value from array to another variable. Can somebody explain me why i cannot do it?

Comment: Why are you saying that you cannot do this?

Comment: if you are trying to create the Fibonacci numbers i think you will get to negative index quite fast with this code values[i] = values[i - values[i - 1]] + values[i - values[i - 2]] say when you get to i = 6 that is you will get values[6] = values[6 - 8] + values[6 - 5] = values[-2] + values[1]. you have to do it like values[i] = values[i - 1] + values[i - 2];

Comment: It's not Fibonacci number, it's similar to Fib: u(n - u(n - 1)) + u(n -u(n - 2)). For i =6 i have values[6] = values[6-values[5]] + values[6-values[4]] where values[5] =3 and values[4] = 3 so i will not have negative index. values[3] = values[n-values[2]] + values[n-values[1]] = values[3-1] + values [3-2] = 1+1 = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `sizeof(int)*n + 1` is equal to `(sizeof(int)*n) + 1`. You allocate space for `n` integer values, plus one ***byte***.

That means your loop in the `else` case *will* write out of bounds (unless `sizeof(int) == 1` which few if any platforms have, even historically). And writing out of bounds of allocated memory leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Often, writing out of bounds messes up the private and internal data used by the memory allocator, leading to problems when calling `free`.

The solution is to either change the allocation so it allocates `n + 1` integers (i.e. `sizeof(int) * (n + 1)`). Or to change the loop condition to `i < n`.

Comment: thanks! what a misstake from me, shame:D. Thanks for very helpfull explain.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the comments.

```
int u(int n)
   {
    if (n < 3)  // moved it here. If n it's smaller you have a smaller array; move it ahead of malloc/free’s
       return 1;
    int* values = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n + 1));
    int out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
       if(i<3) 
          values[i] = 1;
       else
          values[i] = values[i - values[i - 1]] + values[i - values[i - 2]]; // this is suspicious; what do you want to obtain ?
    }

    out = values[n];
    if(values!=NULL)
       free(values);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: 1) Its look better, with your sugesstions. Thanks. I correct my code.

Comment: 2) It's a task from CodeWars, i need to implement function similar to fibonacci series: u(n - u(n - 1)) + u(n -u(n - 2)).